# How to assign values to the classificationAttribute

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

how to input values to the AttributeValueAssignment :                   insert_update AttributeValueAssignment;&Item;attribute(&Item);attributeAssignment(classificationAttribute(code,systemVersion(catalog(id),version)),systemVersion(catalog(id),version),classificationClass(catalogVersion(catalog(id),version),code))[forceWrite=true,unique=true];systemVersion(catalog(id),version);value(code,systemVersion(catalog(id),version))[forceWrite=true,allownull=true,unique=true];

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I found the answer.  $productCatalog=hpeCatalog
$version=Staged
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default=$version])
$clAttrModifiers=system='hpeClassification',version='1.0',translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeTranslator,lang=en
$attributevalue=@product number[$clAttrModifiers]
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$attributevalue;$catalogVersion;
;100686;Shimano XTR FC-M9020-2 Hollowtech 2 / QF 168 36x26 T;